# Method synonyms in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm familiarizing myself with Ruby and it's the first time I see synonyms for methods in the standard library. For now I've found the ones in the Enumerable module:

```
collect <-> map
detect <-> find
include <-> member
etc.
```

Probably other modules contains synonymic methods too. Why are they there? Is it some kind of backward compatibility? Or is it a feature of the language, so the programmer can choose between different options depending on the context to make the program look like plain English?

Comment: +1. Ruby is using synonyms at more occasions, (I think) not just for backwards compatibility but also for readability. E.g., the number of elements in an array can be retrieved with `count`, `length` or `size`. Different words for the same attribute of an array, but by this, Ruby enables you to pick the most appropriate word in your code: do you want the _number_ of items you're collecting, the _length_ of an array, or the current _size_ of the structure? Obviously, they're all the same, but picking the right word makes your code easier to read in your context; a nice property of the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is made to be compatible with other programming languages' word usage.
Ruby is based on Smalltalk. In Smalltalk, `collect` means map. However, most programming languages in the world uses `map`, so Ruby added `map` to make other people feel familiar.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_function for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Synonyms build on the **familiarity** of users coming from different scripting or programming backgrounds with existing nomenclature (e.g. `map`, `grep` etc. are very familiar to people coming from a Perl background.)

It also sometimes comes in handy, indirectly, to have these synonyms, e.g. in Rails [associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html), which is also meant to behave like an enumerable, `find` is overloaded to perform an actual SQL query whereas the `detect` synonym remains available to do the actual enumerable `find`/`detect`.

Comment: I didn't get the find/detect part. Are you saying there's a difference between them in some scenarious?

Comment: @Max: Yes, there will be a difference in scenarios where one of the methods has been overridden and the other hasn't. For example, if I do `def find(*x) nil end`, then `find` will always fail but `detect` will still work.